# How does the Left-Outer Join in Linq (C#) work?

Tags: c#, linq, join

How does the left outer join work? I am aware on how to perform the left outer join, SO has helpful articles and even the official MSDN website has a sleek example, which I will be using here to explain my question.

### My Question in a nutshell

The `from` clause can be used multiple times in the same query which would be treated as sub-queries (source: [from clause (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383978.aspx)). If the second `from` clause is not used on a child of the range element of the first `from` clause then it performs a cross join (source: [from clause (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383978.aspx)). However, we see in the left join example below that the second `from` clause on `gj.DefaultIfEmpty()` does not give the same result, how is that? does the linq query perform some sort of association?

### Example From MSDN

source [How to: Perform Left Outer Joins (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx)

```
    class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    class Pet
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Person Owner { get; set; }
    }

    public static void LeftOuterJoinExample()
    {
        Person magnus = new Person { FirstName = "Magnus", LastName = "Hedlund" };
        Person terry = new Person { FirstName = "Terry", LastName = "Adams" };
        Person charlotte = new Person { FirstName = "Charlotte", LastName = "Weiss" };
        Person arlene = new Person { FirstName = "Arlene", LastName = "Huff" };

        Pet barley = new Pet { Name = "Barley", Owner = terry };
        Pet boots = new Pet { Name = "Boots", Owner = terry };
        Pet whiskers = new Pet { Name = "Whiskers", Owner = charlotte };
        Pet bluemoon = new Pet { Name = "Blue Moon", Owner = terry };
        Pet daisy = new Pet { Name = "Daisy", Owner = magnus };

        // Create two lists.
        List<Person> people = new List<Person> { magnus, terry, charlotte, arlene };
        List<Pet> pets = new List<Pet> { barley, boots, whiskers, bluemoon, daisy };

        var query = from person in people
                    join pet in pets on person equals pet.Owner into gj
                    from subpet in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new { person.FirstName, PetName = (subpet == null ? String.Empty : subpet.Name) };

        foreach (var v in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0,-15}{1}", v.FirstName + ":", v.PetName);
        }
    }

    // This code produces the following output: 
    // 
    // Magnus:         Daisy 
    // Terry:          Barley 
    // Terry:          Boots 
    // Terry:          Blue Moon 
    // Charlotte:      Whiskers 
    // Arlene:
```

### Explanation of the from clause from MSDN

source [from clause (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383978.aspx)

```
class CompoundFrom2
{
    static void Main()
    {
        char[] upperCase = { 'A', 'B', 'C' };
        char[] lowerCase = { 'x', 'y', 'z' };

        // The type of joinQuery1 is IEnumerable<'a>, where 'a 
        // indicates an anonymous type. This anonymous type has two 
        // members, upper and lower, both of type char. 
        var joinQuery1 =
            from upper in upperCase
            from lower in lowerCase
            select new { upper, lower };

        // The type of joinQuery2 is IEnumerable<'a>, where 'a 
        // indicates an anonymous type. This anonymous type has two 
        // members, upper and lower, both of type char. 
        var joinQuery2 =
            from lower in lowerCase
            where lower != 'x'
            from upper in upperCase
            select new { lower, upper };


        // Execute the queries.
        Console.WriteLine("Cross join:");
        // Rest the mouse pointer on joinQuery1 to verify its type. 
        foreach (var pair in joinQuery1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is matched to {1}", pair.upper, pair.lower);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Filtered non-equijoin:");
        // Rest the mouse pointer over joinQuery2 to verify its type. 
        foreach (var pair in joinQuery2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is matched to {1}", pair.lower, pair.upper);
        }

        // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
/* Output:
        Cross join:
        A is matched to x
        A is matched to y
        A is matched to z
        B is matched to x
        B is matched to y
        B is matched to z
        C is matched to x
        C is matched to y
        C is matched to z
        Filtered non-equijoin:
        y is matched to A
        y is matched to B
        y is matched to C
        z is matched to A
        z is matched to B
        z is matched to C
        */
```

### What I have so far

I am guessing the Linq engine does something like this

- Perform a join operation
- Group by the first join member
- for each first join member that is not a empty result from the previous step, append the groupped elements as a child

I of course do not have any reference for this idea but that would make sense and even explains why the `DefaultIfEmpty ()` has to be used.

Comment: Please see http://referencesource.microsoft.com/ for the actual source code, where you can find these kinds of implementation facts. A detailed description of how LINQ is implemented is far too broad for a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the link for reference